# Unable to set AreaPath of a new bug in Azure Devops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

When I programmatically create a new bug and set the area path to this:

```
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken);
new JsonPatchOperation()
{
   Operation = Operation.Add,
   Path = "/fields/System.AreaPath",
   Value = "Project"
},

WorkItem bug = await workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, project, "Bug").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I get this error:

TF401346: Invalid Area/Iteration id given for work item -1, field 'System.AreaId'.

I think this is a bug, this area path exists in ADO.

Comment: Did you look at an existing work item's area path via the API to ensure that you are formatting the value as expected?

Comment: Yes, I query a work item and use the area path of that bug

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you ever find a solution? Entering a "wrong" area path gives me an area path not found error, entering a right one gives me that exact error.

Comment: yes i was, i'd be happy to see if i can help if you want to post your code in an online code editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not the area path but another field, for whatever reason ADO pointed to the area path as the issue. Try adding each field one by one, or area field alone to see if it fixes the issue. This is the trimmed down version of my code.

```
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument
{

     //add fields and their values to your patch document
     new JsonPatchOperation()
     {
         Operation = Operation.Add,
         Path = "/fields/System.Title",
         Value = $"{tag} for PR #{pullRequest.PullRequestId} changes in build {buildNumber} PlannerBuildArtifact."
      },

      new JsonPatchOperation()
      {
          Operation = Operation.Add,
          Path = "/fields/System.AreaPath",
          Value = "Project\\Planner\\Service"
      }
};
try
{
      using VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(Uri, this._credentials);
      using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
      return await workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, Project, "Bug").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (VssException e)
{
      _log.LogError("Unable to create work item", e);
      throw;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case this workaround helps others - the error code `TF401345` is the similar error message with different resolution.

```
TF401345: Area path for work item -1 is invalid
```

The **Area Path** is not the problem - we identified the fix here as *too large of a payload* in **Repro Steps** field. The error message is extremely misleading - just prune down the payload for the field that is too large and chunk it into the ADO Bug discussion. For us an image capture was overflowing the allotted data buffer.